# Redirect website to unknown internal address

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, redirect

A little background of what I'm doing.  I have a home-brew smart thermostat that is connected to my wifi.  The device hosts a website that is used to control everything.  My main gripe is how unreliable it is to access the device via hostname (especially in android which will be the main controller).  I'm trying to find out a way of reliably accessing the device without knowing what the IP address is.

There's two options I'm thinking of, but would like some thoughts on if there are better ways of doing it, or other possible downfalls for my ideas here.

**External Website**

1. After wifi configuration, device turns on and sends its internal IP to an external server
2. External server gets request and logs external IP and associated internal IP
3. User goes to external website: my.thermostat.com
4. Website looks up external IP from request, determines internal IP
5. Website redirects page to internal IP

Therefore, going to my.thermostat.com will redirect to the internal IP.

Downsides:

- Requires internet access
- Multiple devices with the same external ip?

**Android/iOS App**

1. Launch app
2. App scans current subnet for device
3. Sends request to each IP: http://x.x.x.x/isThermostat.html
4. When an expected response is received, launch browser to that IP

Downsides:

- Requires app to access control panel
- What to do if you want to access via computer?  Rely on hostname?

The app route seems like it would be the least complicated, but I like the idea of being able to access the thermostat with any device, so it would still be a little tricky on computers.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Giving some more info on the hardware itself, it's an arduino yun that will either be connected either via ethernet or wifi.  I'd like to stay away from static configurations or setting static DHCP leases.  I imagine making a couple of these to give to friends and whatnot, so the least amount of user setup the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up going with the android app that scans the local subnet for the device.  I have an html file on the server called knockknock.html that simply has the text "HELLO".  For anyone interested, here's a first rendition of the code I'm using:

```
/*
 * Get the IP and subnet info and start scanning the local subnet
 */
void findServer() {
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    DhcpInfo dhcp = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
    if (dhcp == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No DHCPInfo on WiFi side.");
    }

    //Get the string verison of the IP/subnet from the int given by WifiManager
    final String ip = intToIp(dhcp.ipAddress);
    final String mask = intToIp(dhcp.netmask);

    //Start the scanner on a separate thread from the UI
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            serverScanner(ip, mask);
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}

/*
 * Convert an integer to a human readable format
 */
String intToIp(int i) {
    return  ( i & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((i >> 16 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
            ((i >> 24 ) & 0xFF ) ;
}

/*
 * Scan the given subnet for the server
 */
void serverScanner(String ip, String netmask) {
    //Get the first part of the IP
    //TODO: Add support for various subnet masks
    String iIPv4 = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf("."));
    iIPv4 += ".";
    Log.v(TAG, "Current IP Structure: " + iIPv4);

    // Loop to scan each address on the local subnet
    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        //Check to see if the server exists
        if (checkServer(iIPv4 + i)) {
            //It does exist, so let's set the variable and preferences
            mServerIP = iIPv4 + i;

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("LastServerIP", mServerIP);
            editor.commit();
            return;  //And we're done here
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Send a request to the server and see if it's alive and what we're looking for
 */
boolean checkServer(String ip) {
    BufferedReader inputStream = null;

    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://" + ip + "/knockknock.html");
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 100);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 100);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String result = convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();

            if (result.equals("HELLO\n")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    //No response or not the response we're looking for, so return false
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an static internal IP ?

Normally in your home router you have a option to give static IP to a given MAC address, or you the definition of the device to setup the static IP.

I think both of your solutions are two complex for something simple.

Comment: It's an option, but I'm trying to make this not so involved from a user standpoint.  Perfect example: if you got a nest would you want to set up a static internal IP in order to control it?  I'd rather do more work on my end to make it easier for the user.

Comment: Ok, I think the second option is the best (and I think if the one used on other brands device to search for compatible devices inside the network). For example, Ubiquiti have a lot of devices. Per default they have DHCP turn on, and I manually like to assign to a specific IP. In the other hand they have a Controller (software) so search the devices and add to the configuration file.

In you case I will go for the App, and if you have 2 or more devices, the one single app can track them and keep the information.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @SpeedDragon, I will pursue the 2nd option.  Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a static IP for the device, disabling DHCP on the device and configuring a static IP in the router that refers to the MAC hardware address of the device. This should avoid problems with changing a hostname. Essentially it will allow for you to refer the address within the LAN with a consistent IP.

You haven't mentioned exactly what device it is, so I can't suggest a clear configuration setup, but you should be able to Google for answers. What you do next depends on what you need to achieve.

If you need to access the device from the WAN (Internet) then you need a dynamic DNS service like https://duckdns.org/why.jsp

A DDNS is a hosted service that forwards requests to a subdomain, like: thermostat.duckdns.org to your WAN IP (your router/modem). You install a helper application inside your network that lets the DDNS know every 5 minutes what your WAN IP is, therefore keeping it pointing at you.

From there if you visit: thermostat.duckdns.org it will forward you to your WAN IP, from which point your router then decides what to do with the request. You'll want to setup your router to port forward (port 80 for a web server such as apache) that points to your internal static IP of your thermostat device. Your device then serves the website.

This method allows you to run a web server on an computer or device within a LAN that is accessible from WAN (Internet).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as mentioned in my comment on @SpeedDragon answer I'm trying to stay away from static configurations to make it as user friendly as possible.  I'm updating the question to give a little more info on the equipment.

Comment: I'm afraid your users are going to experience configuration issues with any WAN method. ISP's sometimes block port 80 inbound for your protection (can be disabled if you are lucky), so your users may have to deal with problems no matter what method you choose.

Comment: Initially I'm not too concerned with external access.  I have a few ideas to handle that, but that's a whole different section :)